# Зачем нужен Gulp?

Tags: html, css, gulp, frontend, sass

Подскажите, пожалуйста, перед началом веб-разработки, всегда нужно подключать Gulp и все плагины к нему? Просто начал изучение данного инструмента и задаюсь вопросом, на сколько Gulp обязателен в работе Front-end разработчика ?

Спасибо!

Comment: Может и не нужен, ведь есть webpack

Answer (score 1):

Может быть Вам СЕЙЧАС и не нужен gulp, все инструменты становятся полезны не раньше чем вы осознаете их полезность, gulp это система упрощающая разработку и сборку.

Однако на в начале процесса обучения, как мне кажется, важнее познать это кунг-фу сначала в ручном режиме, чтобы понимать, где больно и что необходимо автоматизировать, а не бездумно подключать все подряд плагины и фичи, потому, что так надо.

Для gulp есть альтернативы(webpack например),  основной его плюс (который иногда минус) это многопоточность, тоесть он запускает ваши сборочные задачи параллельно.

Потом фронтенд фронтенду рознь, не всегда приходится возится со всеми аспектами веб разработки, и когда все ограничивается лишь javascript, тогда достаточно просто написать build script для npm и забыть

Comment: RequireJS — это же не сборщик, а модульная система )

Comment: верное замечание

Answer (score 0):

Берет всю рутину на себя. Можешь и без него работать, но самое простое что приходит в голову - это обновление браузера при верстке, расставление префиксов, сборщик из sass в min.css и многое другое.

p.s. может меня поправят более опытные люди, я тоже только начинающий)